# Web application - Select different column based on user input JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl

Web application contains two pages

**1.index.jsp
2.result.jsp**

index page contains input values such as weeknum,sla etc , user has to fill the input values , after that query will be executed in result page

*This is my database table*

```
weeknum groupby images  actct   sla24   sla8    CTSUM   type
1       studio  123     8.5 5   11      16      16     short
1       studio  12      9.5 6   12      16      12     long
1       studio  154     10.5    7       13      16      short
2       studio  123     11.5    8       14      16      long
2       studio  12      12.5    9       15      16      short
2       studio  154     13.5    10      16      16      long
```

And below is jsp page database query (resultPage)

```
"<sql:query var=""retouch"" dataSource=""jdbc/imaging"">
                SELECT WEEKNUM,
                       GROUPBY,
                       SUM(IMAGES) AS IMAGES,
                       SUM(SLA24) AS SLA24,
                       ROUND(SUM(CTSUM)/SUM(IMAGES),2) AS AVGCT,
                        ROUND(SUM(SLA24)/SUM(IMAGES)*100,2) AS CTPERC 
                FROM (SELECT                                                                              
                            WEEKNUM,
                            COLUMNTYPE as groupby,
                            IMAGES,
                            ActCT,
                            IMAGES * AVGCT AS CTSUM,
                            SLA24,SLA8 
                FROM RETOUCHSUMMARY
               WHERE WEEKNUM = ?
                     <sql:param value=""${param.weeknum}"" /> )AS CT GROUP BY    
                      WEEKNUM,COLUMNTYPE;
            </sql:query>"
```

The above query works fine,by default it picks sla24 column.
it is possible , if user selects sla8 in index page query has to pick sla8 column inside of sla24 ..?

Hope i explained well, Please help

Comment: How does this question is related to _java,jsp,jstl_ , seems you need to form a sql query and `<sql:query>` can be used for prototyping purpose , not for real time process

Comment: Sorry .. im new to this .. developing web application in netbeans .. i hope you understand my question , if so you are free to edit my question :)

Comment: If that is the application rather than a prototype i suggest you to follow the mvc pattern to populate the select box values based on previous select

Comment: Its very basic application , Based on user input ( SLA ) , query has to pick the column ?

Comment: First of all, your query looks very strange to me. Second, i don't see sla24, ctsum column in your table. After FROM clause you should use name of the table, you are using a subquery in which you select some columns from RETOUCHSUMMARY table, which i have no idea where it is.

Comment: Sorry corrected my post , see now